# React NextJS works locally but I cannot run "npm run build". Maybe "> Build failed because of webpack errors" is causing it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Below is what I get in my terminal when I try to build. Locally, everything runs perfectly fine.

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

./public/img/bg-video-poster.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)

Import trace for requested module:
./src/components/Home.js
./pages/index-image-overlay.js

Build failed because of webpack errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.